# How to set hostname on Lucid Lynx?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I am installing a new Lucid Lynx server, and need to set the hostname.

I tried:

```
echo "squire" > /etc/hostname 
hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

That didn't work. anyone knows how to set the hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the appropriate method from a normal user account is

```
sudo hostname testbox
```

Which successfully sets the hostname of my Lucid Lynx box to "testbox"

Comment: Thanks: this is the first time I got an answer answered so quickly. many thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

As an asside, don't forget to add your new hostname in /etc/hosts, or else sudo (and a couple other things) will complain about unknown hosts.

Example: I changed my hostname from localhost to "tara" using `sudo hostname tara`, so I edited the line in /etc/hosts that was

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

and made it

```
127.0.0.1 localhost tara
```

(because I still wanted "localhost" to work, too)

Answer (score 0):

Hostname -F does not work for me either. But try /etc/init.d/networking restart and ping your new hostname. Will be ok.